# Javascript window.location.href not working if application is hosted on IIS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis

I have a problem regarding the javascript `window.location.href` function.
On the development server(Windows server 2008 with IIS) we have an asp.net application deployed in the "default web site" named Topics2 (it's a test application - the production one is Topics).

My problem is:
When i want to navigate to another page using javascript `window.location.href` the browser redirects me to the production page and not the test page. 
Example: Instead of bringing me to `server/Topics2/MyPage.aspx?id=100` it brings me to `server/MyPage.aspx?id=100` (the Topics name is not shown).

There is no routing made in the application. Is IIS adding some default routing? Or could there be any routing made (that i'm not aware of) in IIS that is messing this up?

What i tried untill now: 

1.  `window.location.href = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/MyPage.aspx?id=" + item.value;`

2. `window.location.href= "/MyPage.aspx?id="+item.value;`


I know i can always hardcode the "Topics2" name but that's not wanted because we don't want to have that in mind every time we deploy to the production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, which is pretty simple (shame on me that i didn't think of that!).

So, apparently if I type `window.location.href= "/MyPage.aspx?id="+item.value;` the server redirects me to the production server but if i type `window.location.href= "./MyPage.aspx?id="+item.value;` it takes me to the right page.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
location.replace(yourUrl);
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try using this"?

Comment: Tried using `location.replace("/MyPage.aspx?id="+item.value);`  but the problem is still there.
<br />
Even with `location.replace(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/MyPage.aspx?id=" + item.value);` it still redirects me to the production server.